# Top part of box shadow clipped in IE only

Tags: css, internet-explorer

On my site I have links with a box shadow that appears when hovering. You can see it on http://www.lorteau.fr . That works just fine on Chrome, Opera and Firefox. IE however clips the top of it.

Chrome, Opera, Firefox:
[image]

IE: [image]

HTML defining the links and all the containers around it:

```
<body>
<div class="main m-scene" id="page">
    <div id="menu">
        <a class="menu_link" id="wphone_link" href="wphone.html">Windows Phone</a>
        <a class="menu_link" id="wmetro_link" href="wmetro.html">Windows Metro</a>
        <a class="menu_link" id="wdesktop_link" href="wdesktop.html">Windows Desktop</a>
        <a class="menu_link" id="linux_link" href="linux.html">Linux</a>
        <a class="menu_link" id="other_link" href="other.html">Other</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS3 defining the hovering effect and the containers around it:

```
.html
{
    background-color: #464646;
}

body
{
    margin: 0;
}

#page
{
    width: 900px;
    min-width: 800px;
    min-height: 100%;
    -pie-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #FFFFFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    background-image: none;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
    background-color: #3C3C3C;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 7px 5px 6px 32px;
}
#menu
{
    height: 57px;
    display: block;
    width: 85%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu_link, .menu_link:hover
{
    font-family: 'Electrolize', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #777777;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #777777;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: 250ms linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: 250ms linear 0s;
    -o-transition: 250ms linear 0s;
    transition: 250ms linear 0s;
}

.menu_link:hover
{
    color: #FFBE5B;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(255, 190, 91, 0.5);
}

.menu_link:active
{
    color: #FFBE5B;
}

.m-scene .scene_element
{
    animation-duration: 0.25s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.25s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

I tried all the padding, margin and height combinations I could think of but that didn't change anything. Would some have an idea as to what I could modify so that the shadow isn't clipped on any browser?

Comment: What version of IE are you referring too? When I view your site in the IE emulator (IE-9-11) everything shows correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. IE11 but I fixed it already, see below. I can't mark my answer as being the solution until 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pff never mind. Removed "margin-top: 5px;" from #menu and added "padding-top: 15px;" and that did it.

Spelling out the question clearly always helps!